# Need help understanding the solution to this question

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

The sets $P$ and $C$ are specified in the following way:

$$
\begin{gathered}P=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}|y\geq x^{2}+x\} \end{gathered}
$$
$$
\begin{gathered}C=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R\}|\left( x+\frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}  +\left( y+\frac{1}{2} \right)^{2}  \leq \frac{1}{16} } \end{gathered}
$$

Prove or disprove the following statement:

$$
a) \left( \exists \left( x,y\right)  \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}\right)  \left( \left( x,y\right)  \in P\wedge \left( x,y\right)  \in C\right)  )
$$

Anyone know how to determine the $x$, and $y$?

I know a good first step would be to
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs9Ow.png) both sets.

We know one set is a parabolic disk, and the other is a disk. The equation of a circle is in the form:

$$
x^2 + y^2 = z^2
$$

And in this case, it has its centre at:

$$
x=-\frac{1}{2}; y=-\frac{1}{2};$$ and the radius is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{16}},$
i.e. it would be the interior of the circle that has the radius $\frac{1}{4}.$

But my teacher wrote that we should assume $x = -1/2$, and $y = -1/4$, but I am not sure why they got $-1/4$ for $y$. Here's [[1](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/903463352582434866/1026439673024872448/3006A191-5BFE-4944-86F5-5A9B387C8E1F.png), [2]](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/903463352582434866/1026440648439648256/Skarmavbild_2022-10-03_kl._12.28.35.png) their solution.

Could someone explain what we're trying to do here?

Comment: The question was: find some point in $P\cap C$. There is in fact a unique solution $(-0.5,-0.25)$, which they guessed graphically  (the parabola and the circle are tangent at that point) and then checked by calculation. (That point is of course not the center of the circle.)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You inadvertently transformed some symbols in the definition of $C$ into bold: $\mathbb{x, 16}$, etc.

Comment: @Théophile . I'll see to it. I'm busy answering queries to my A.

Answer (score 0):

$ (1)...\quad (x,y)\in P \implies y\ge x^2+x=(x+1/2)^2-1/4\ge -1/4.$

$(2)... \quad (x,y)\in C \implies (y+1/2)^2\le (y+1/2)^2+(x+1/2)^2\le 1/16 \implies$

$\implies |y+1/2|\le 1/4\implies y\in [-3/4,-1/4]\implies y\le -1/4.$

Therefore $(x,y)\in P\cap C\implies y=-1/4.$

And by $(1)$ we have $(x,-1/4)\in P \iff x=-1/2.$

And we see that $(-1/2,-1/4)$ does also belong to $C.$

Comment: Don't believe my answers until 10 minutes after posting. I always have to fix my killer typos.

Comment: Can you explain (1) for me please? Is P = (x, y) the same as (x, y) ∈ P?

Further, how do you go from ≥²+ to (+1/2)²−1/4≥-1/4?

Comment: Would appreciate if you could explain this to a newbie ”(+1/2)²≤(+1/2)²+(+1/2)²≤1/16⟹ 

⟹|+1/2|≤1/4⟹∈[−3/4,−1/4]⟹≤−1/4."

Comment: @AFM . I will answer soon. I am very tired right now.